# CSV file can. not be converted into a float

Tags: python, csv, valueerror

Im currently trying to test an ANN on a data csv file. This code works no problem the first time round when im training the ANN but this error shows up when I do it for the test. If I run the program again it spits out the answer but obviously I don't want the have to continuously rerun it every time

Code

```
   # load the mnist test data CSV file into a list 
    test_data_file = open("mnist_test.csv", 'r') 
    test_data_list = test_data_file.readlines() 
    test_data_file.close() 
 # go through all the records in the test data set
 for record in test_data_list:
     # split the record by the ',' commas
all_values = record.split(',')
# correct answer is first value
correct_label = int(all_values[0])
# scale and shift the inputs
inputs = (numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:])/255.0*0.99)+0.01
# query the network
outputs = n.query(inputs)
# the index of the highest value corresponds to the label
label = numpy.argmax(outputs)
# append correct or incorrect to list
if (label == correct_label):
    # network's answer matches correct answer, add 1 to scorecard
    scorecard.append(1)
else:
    # network's answer doesn't match correct answer, add 0 to scorecard
    scorecard.append(0)
```

Error

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-7-026bfaa95a53> in <module>
 11     correct_label = int(all_values[0])
 12     # scale and shift the inputs
 ---> 13     inputs = (numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:])/255.0*0.99)+0.01
 14     # query the network
 15     outputs = n.query(inputs)

 <__array_function__ internals> in asfarray(*args, **kwargs)

 ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py in asfarray(a, dtype)
113     if not _nx.issubdtype(dtype, _nx.inexact):
114         dtype = _nx.float_
  --> 115     return asarray(a, dtype=dtype)
116 
117 

 ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
 83 
 84     """
   ---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
 86 
 87 

  ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: You tried to convert an empty string to a float. Since we don't have the data its hard to say, but, in `record.split(',')` - if there is a trailing comma or two commas in a row, you get an empty string in the list. Add `print(record, all_values)` after the spilt and see if you have empty columns.

Comment: I think the indentation is a bit messed up in the posted code - no body after the `for`. It would help to tidy that up.

Comment: the section before it opens that data, here is the code if it.

      # load the mnist test data CSV file into a list
      test_data_file = open("mnist_test.csv", 'r')
      test_data_list = test_data_file.readlines()
      test_data_file.close()

When it tried to print it did load all the values but I still got the same error code when I ran the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error because `numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:])` found empty strings in the list. These came from `record.split(',')` which means your original CSV file has some empty columns in some of the rows. That begs the question whether that's legal for your data and what a good default in that case is.

Since your data is a integer column 0 with the remaining columns being floats, you can skip reading the file on your own and use `numpy.genfromtxt()` to build an array from the entire file all in one call. Then, you can pull out the `correct_label` and process the array as a whole. I chose `np.nan` to fill the empty cells - that's just a guess, you may want to use a different value.

I'm a little fuzzy about what is happening towards the end of your script. But I think that building the right array and then using a `for` loop to enumerate its rows, I am doing the same thing.... whatever that is!

```
import numpy as np

# read in entire data set
arr = np.genfromtxt("test.csv", dtype='f8', delimiter=',',
    missing_values=np.nan, filling_values=np.nan)

# column 0 is really integer correct labels, so extract to 1d array
correct_labels = arr[0].astype('i8')

# scale and shift remaining columns
arr = (np.delete(arr, 0, axis=1)*255.0*0.99)+0.01

for inputs in arr:
    outputs = n.query(inputs)
    # the index of the highest value corresponds to the label
    label = numpy.argmax(outputs)
    # append correct or incorrect to list
    if (label == correct_label):
        # network's answer matches correct answer, add 1 to scorecard
        scorecard.append(1)
    else:
        # network's answer doesn't match correct answer, add 0 to scorecard
        scorecard.append(0)
```

Comment: thanks so much, the code work but my performance is now down to 10% when it was originally up at 95% ill have to go back through my code and find what else I've done wrong aha

Comment: Not sure what the performance difference is. You should get a small win from the csv reading part. Other than that, it should pretty much be a wash. Good luck!